# Moving a sprite to the other side when a sprite moves off screen Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

If I have a sprite (See below) that I can move around, the screen with the arrow keys. (Up and Down moves forwards and backwards, left and right turn.)
I was wondering if it would be possible to move to the other side of the screen when it goes off? But so it works whatever the angle is, and so that if it's driven half into the edge, half appears on one side. (Kind of like snake) Is there a way of doing this?

[image: Car]

Here's my code so far:

```
import sys, pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
car = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Car.png').convert_alpha(), (64, 64))
pygame.display.set_caption('Car Game')
pygame.display.set_icon(car)
FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

carX  = 400
carY  = 100
angle = 90
speed = 0

while True:

    if angle == 360: angle = 0
    if  angle == -1: angle = 359

    SCREEN.fill((0,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_a] or keys[K_LEFT]:
        angle += speed
    elif keys[K_d] or keys[K_RIGHT]:
        angle -= speed
    if keys[K_w] or keys[K_UP]:
        speed += 1
    elif keys[K_s] or keys[K_DOWN]:
        speed -= 0.5

    carX += speed*math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    carY -= speed*math.sin(math.radians(angle))
    speed *= 0.95

    rotcar = pygame.transform.rotate(car, angle)
    position = rotcar.get_rect(center = (carX,carY))
    SCREEN.blit(rotcar, position)

    pygame.display.update()
    FPS.tick(24)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with pygame, so here's a starting point for you. The _term_ you are looking for to describe what you want to achieve is **wrapping** or **wraparound** because as your object goes _off_ screen, it comes back on the other side, rather than _side scrolling_.

To achieve that, start by changing your car's position as it goes off screen; a simple pygame example of that can be seen here [screen wrap boundaries](http://cs.iupui.edu/~aharris/pygame/ch08/wrap.py). Take a look at the `def checkBounds(self)` function.

Comment: @JonathonOgden Is there of making half the car appear on both sides though?

Comment: I will investigate for you. I assume pygame doesn't handle the drawing of each section of the car on both sides if you position it on/off screen then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with pygame but I think [this game](http://dr0id.homepage.bluewin.ch/BETA/spacegame.zip) (md5: 92f9f508cbe2d015b18376fb083e0064  file: spacegame.zip) has the feature you're looking for. Thanks to the author, DR0ID_ , for making it publicly available on [his/her website](http://dr0id.homepage.bluewin.ch)

To implement the "wrap around" feature in your car game I used this function from "game.py":

```
def draw(self, surface):
    wrap = 0
    for s in self.sprites():
        r = s.rect
        if r.left<0:
            r.move_ip(800, 0)
            wrap = 1
        elif r.right > 800:
            r.move_ip(-800, 0)
            wrap = 1
        if r.top < 0:
            r.move_ip(0, 600)
            wrap = 1
        elif r.bottom > 600:
            r.move_ip(0, -600)
            wrap = 1
        if wrap:
            surface_blit(s.image, r)
            wrap = 0
```

After a few adjustments I ended up with this working example:

```
import sys, pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

# Added HEIGHT and WIDTH as fixed variables 

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

car = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Car.png').convert_alpha(), (64, 64))
pygame.display.set_caption('Car Game')
pygame.display.set_icon(car)
FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

carX  = 400
carY  = 100
angle = 90
speed = 0

while True:

    if angle == 360: angle = 0
    if  angle == -1: angle = 359

    SCREEN.fill((0,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_a] or keys[K_LEFT]:
        angle += speed
    elif keys[K_d] or keys[K_RIGHT]:
        angle -= speed
    if keys[K_w] or keys[K_UP]:
        speed += 1
    elif keys[K_s] or keys[K_DOWN]:
        speed -= 0.5

    carX += speed*math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    carY -= speed*math.sin(math.radians(angle))
    speed *= 0.95

    rotcar = pygame.transform.rotate(car, angle)
    position = rotcar.get_rect(center = (carX,carY))

    # Basically a copy/paste of the "draw"-function from the spacegame.zip

    wrap_around = False

    if position[0] <  0 :
        # off screen left
        position.move_ip(WIDTH, 0)
        wrap_around = True

    if position[0]  + rotcar.get_width() > WIDTH:
        # off screen right
        position.move_ip(-WIDTH, 0)
        wrap_around = True

    if position[1]  < 0:
        # off screen top
        position.move_ip(0, HEIGHT) 
        wrap_around = True

    if position[1] + rotcar.get_height() > HEIGHT:
        # off screen bottom
        position.move_ip(0, -HEIGHT) 
        wrap_around = True

    if wrap_around:

        SCREEN.blit(rotcar, position)


    position[0] %= WIDTH
    position[1] %= HEIGHT  
    carX %= WIDTH
    carY %= HEIGHT


    SCREEN.blit(rotcar, position)

    pygame.display.update()
    FPS.tick(24)
```

Comment: nice work. Was just looking through the spacegame source myself a couple of hours ago.

Comment: @JonathonOgden Thanks! I guess Google shines on DR0ID_'s spacegame :)

Comment: Its always a pleasure to see that my code helped someone, even if it is an old one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "elif"-statements, you can just set the coordinates "modulo" (%) screen-width / screen height, for x and y coordinates individually.