# Pygame checking for collision not working

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on a Snake game and I'm trying to detect the collision between the head and the tail of the snake.

```
class Snake():
def __init__(self, screen, startx, starty, width, height, color):
    self.screen = screen
    self.startx = startx
    self.starty = starty
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.color = color
    self.amount_tiles = 5
    self.tile = 0
    self.position = []
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(startx, starty, width, height)   #rectangle 1: Head of the Snake
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, self.rect)
```

-

```
def existing_tiles(self):
    self.count = self.tile

    while self.count > 0:
        self.current_pos = self.position
        x = self.current_pos[self.count - 1]
        self.rect_new = pygame.Rect(x[0], x[1], self.width, self.height) #rectangle 2:Tail of the Snake
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, GREEN, self.rect_new)
        self.count = self.count - 1
```

I tried using pygame.Rect.colliderect(rect1,rect2) as I did before with the Snake Head and the Food rectangle but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Console output: AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'rect_new'
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import pygame
import random

RED = (255,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,128,255)

#------------------------------FUNCTIONS--------------------------------#
def main():

    pygame.init()
    display_width=460
    display_height=460
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 10

    schlange = Snake(gameDisplay, 220, 220, 20, 20, BLUE)
    essen = Food(gameDisplay)
    speed = (0,0)

    while True:
            #event loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    speed = (0, -20)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    speed = (0, 20)
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    speed = (-20, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    speed = (20, 0)

        if pygame.Rect.colliderect(schlange.rect, essen.rect) == True:
            essen = Food(gameDisplay)
            schlange.eat()

        if pygame.Rect.colliderect(schlange.rect, schlange.rect_new) == True:
            print('rip')
            pygame.quit()
            quit()


        schlange.move(speed[0], speed[1])
        essen.spawn()
        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()

#------------------------------CLASSES---------------------------------#
class Snake():
    def __init__(self, screen, startx, starty, width, height, color):
        self.screen = screen
        self.startx = startx
        self.starty = starty
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.amount_tiles = 5
        self.tile = 0
        self.position = []
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(startx, starty, width, height)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, self.rect)

    def move(self, x_change, y_change):
        self.screen.fill(WHITE)
        self.x_change = x_change
        self.y_change = y_change
        self.position.insert(0, (self.startx, self.starty))

        self.pos = self.position[self.tile]

        '''self.add_tile()'''
        self.existing_tiles()

        self.startx += x_change
        self.starty += y_change
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.startx, self.starty, self.width, self.height)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)

    def existing_tiles(self):
        self.count = self.tile

        while self.count > 0:
            self.current_pos = self.position
            x = self.current_pos[self.count - 1]
            self.rect_new = pygame.Rect(x[0], x[1], self.width, self.height)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, GREEN, self.rect_new)
            self.count = self.count - 1


    '''def add_tile(self):
        x = self.pos[0]
        y = self.pos[1]
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, GREEN, (x, y, self.width, self.height))'''

    def eat(self):
        self.amount_tiles += 1
        self.tile += 1




class Food():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.width = 20
        self.height = 20
        self.spawnx = random.randrange(0, 460, 20)
        self.spawny = random.randrange(0, 460, 20)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.spawnx, self.spawny, self.width, self.height)

    def spawn(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, RED, self.rect)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your error is telling you what is wrong. Your snake object is not a rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the edited version of your game below. I made two changes and wrote a few notes in the code.

```
import pygame
import random

RED = (255,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,128,255)

#------------------------------FUNCTIONS--------------------------------#
def main():

    pygame.init()
    display_width=460
    display_height=460
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 10

    schlange = Snake(gameDisplay, 220, 220, 20, 20, BLUE)
    essen = Food(gameDisplay)
    speed = (0,0)

    while True:
            #event loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    speed = (0, -20)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    speed = (0, 20)
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    speed = (-20, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    speed = (20, 0)

        if pygame.Rect.colliderect(schlange.rect, essen.rect) == True:
            essen = Food(gameDisplay)
            schlange.eat()

        """ ADDED """

        """ I realized that you're storing the tail pieces in self.position.
            Iterating through this list and checking for collisions seems to do the trick.
            Skip check when there's only one element in schlange.position to avoid a collision as soon as the game starts.
            Now you probably just need to prevent the snake from going straight back 
            into itself (180 degree turn) since that would trigger a collision that you might not want """

        if len(schlange.position) > 1:
            for coords in schlange.position:
                if pygame.Rect.colliderect(schlange.rect, pygame.Rect(coords[0], coords[1], schlange.width, schlange.height)) == True:
                    print('rip')
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()            

        """ /ADDED """


        schlange.move(speed[0], speed[1])
        essen.spawn()
        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()

#------------------------------CLASSES---------------------------------#
class Snake():
    def __init__(self, screen, startx, starty, width, height, color):
        self.screen = screen
        self.startx = startx
        self.starty = starty
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.amount_tiles = 5
        self.tile = 0
        self.position = []
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(startx, starty, width, height)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, self.rect)

    def move(self, x_change, y_change):
        self.screen.fill(WHITE)
        self.x_change = x_change
        self.y_change = y_change
        self.position.insert(0, (self.startx, self.starty))

        self.pos = self.position[self.tile]

        '''self.add_tile()'''
        self.existing_tiles()

        self.startx += x_change
        self.starty += y_change
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.startx, self.starty, self.width, self.height)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)


        """ ADDED """

        """ You kept adding to self.position but never deleted any elements. 
            That's unnecessary and would eventually cause a MemoryError """

        if len(self.position) > self.tile+1:
            del self.position[-1]

        """ /ADDED """

    def existing_tiles(self):
        self.count = self.tile

        while self.count > 0:
            self.current_pos = self.position
            x = self.current_pos[self.count - 1]
            self.rect_new = pygame.Rect(x[0], x[1], self.width, self.height)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, GREEN, self.rect_new)
            self.count = self.count - 1


    '''def add_tile(self):
        x = self.pos[0]
        y = self.pos[1]
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, GREEN, (x, y, self.width, self.height))'''

    def eat(self):
        self.amount_tiles += 1
        self.tile += 1




class Food():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.width = 20
        self.height = 20
        self.spawnx = random.randrange(0, 460, 20)
        self.spawny = random.randrange(0, 460, 20)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.spawnx, self.spawny, self.width, self.height)

    def spawn(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, RED, self.rect)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I wonder why this was down-voted. Am I doing something moronic without realizing? The code could probably be rewritten for clarity and efficiency but that's OP's business as I see it.

Comment: Hehe thanks, don't worry :) Glad it's working. I'm pretty new as well and never wrote anything in pygame except another answer here on stackoverflow so perhaps there was a valid reason for down-voting that I'm just too noob to realize :D An explanation would be nice. Oh well. Anyway, [the other pygame answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728199/moving-a-sprite-to-the-other-side-when-a-sprite-moves-off-screen-pygame/35748930#35748930) might actually be relevant for you as well. I remember Snake (or was it Snake 2?) having the same "wrap around"-effect that OP was asking for.

Comment: Oh yeah I was going to implement that aswell or atlest try to :D Now I don't have to make a new question when I'm stuck on that, thanks :) Still one question, apart from all the other improvements you made on my code. Why did my initial thought not work ? schlange.rect is a rectangle and schlange.rect_new is one. Why didnt it work like the if statement right  above it (if pygame.Rect.colliderect(schlange.rect, essen.rect) == True:)?